# Android app check for Instagram account on the device

Tags: android, instagram

I am developing an app to get images from an `Instagram` account. I would like to know if is possible to know if there are already an `Instagram` account on the device.

Thanks!

Comment: have you taken a look at [instagram's api](https://www.instagram.com/developer/)?

Comment: Yes of course, I have already implemented an app to login/logout and download images from the Instagram account and I have followed this documentation